# Is the efficiency of poisonous colors decreased?

Tags: the-void

Using color damages a Sister's realm. The damage is smaller per point if the color is poisonous to her, and bigger per point if it is a favored color. The implications for farming are clear: infuse trees with poisonous color to mitigate realm damage.

What about combat? Aside from realm damage, is the power of the colors affected as well? Do ten points of a favored color have the same amount of attack power as ten points of a nature-friendly, poisonous color? Does the duration of golems or other glyphs depend on color type as well as the amount used?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes and no.

Imbuing glyphs with larger amounts of colour **does** make them more powerful/last longer. However, each glyph has a maximum limit, after which colour no longer increases its potency. Fortunately, excess colour is just returned to your palette, rather than being lost.

As far as I can find there is no released data as to what the maximum amount of colour per glyph is. I did find, however, according to [a guide on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/970707-the-void/faqs/62846) (sections [7.02] and [8.01]), that the "Hawk" glyph has a maximum of 32. The author says they have spoken to one of the devs about a number of workings in the game (see section [9.00]), so I assume that this is where the information came from.

In regards to which colour is used, I can find nothing to say that a favoured/poisonous colour in different realms make glyphs more or less powerful. So I will cautiously say that the colour used **does not** matter. When realms take damage though, Brothers do become weaker anyway. they also have a colour wheel with a weakness, though this is not extended to regular enemies.